# Problems updating system with apt-get

Tags: upgrade, apt, updates

After trying `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` I have the following error message:
This is a coppy of my terminal (in spanish)

```
root@LinuxJGP:/home/javiergp# apt-get upgrade
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho
Creando árbol de dependencias       
Leyendo la información de estado... Hecho
Se actualizarán los siguientes paquetes:
  apport apport-symptoms fonts-liberation gnome-icon-theme gnome-orca language-pack-en language-pack-en-base
  language-pack-es language-pack-es-base language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base
  language-pack-gnome-es language-pack-gnome-es-base light-themes linux-firmware oneconf resolvconf
  sessioninstaller software-center ssl-cert tzdata ubuntu-docs ubuntu-keyring ubuntu-sso-client
  ubuntuone-control-panel ubuntuone-installer unity-lens-video unity-scope-video-remote xdiagnose
29 actualizados, 0 se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 0 no actualizados.
E: Los archivos de índice de paquetes están dañados. No existe un campo «Filename:» para el paquete ubuntu-keyring.
```

How can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your spanish error is the equivalent of this English one:

```
 the package index files are corrupted. no filename field for package
```

This would mean you have a problem with the listings (index) of all packages: they are broken. [This Thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1914808) implies that you might have success with removing the lists directory.

So you might want to delete everything in `/var/lib/apt/lists/`, and then update your apt again

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

MIND YOU, I have not tried this, but [it seems](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1939591) like this isn't a real dangerous thing to do.

> The /var/lib/apt/lists can be removed and recreated safely. An 'apt-get update' will repopulate the necessary information. This does not impact the history of installed packages.

Comment: The origional thread also mentions that the user had a problem with the `rm` command, as there was a directory called `partial` in there. You can obviously remove that one to by using `rm -r`, but that is more of a "how does `rm` work" problem :D